# Modeless Qt window on top of parent, but not on top of other applications

Tags: qt, user-interface, window

I wish to have a Qt dialog window that:

1. always stays on top of its parent (the main application window),
2. allows the user to interact with the parent window, and
3. does not always stay on top of other applications.

I've been able to achieve 1 and 3 by making the dialog modal, and I can achieve 1 and 2 by using the Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint window flag.  But I cannot manage to make all three work - is it possible?

In case answers are OS-specific, I mainly work on a Mac, but I would prefer a solution that also applies to Windows and Linux.  Thanks!

Comment: Did you achieve this since asking the question?
I am in the same situation right now, and can't find a way to make it work.

Comment: In the end I found two solutions: 1) Felix's suggestion for changing the window flags based on the application state. Works, but a bit hacky and can flicker. 2) Using the Qt::Tool window flag on the dialog. This does everything I want except on macOS it means the dialog window is invisible when the main application is not in focus.

Comment: Thank you! I arrived at the same conclusion, and used the Qt::Tool type, and put up with them disappearing on macOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to use [`QGuiApplication::applicationStateChanged`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#applicationStateChanged). This way you get notified if the user enters or leaves your application. Just dynamically add and remove the `Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint` flag for your window. If you have multiple windows, you can use [`QGuiApplication::focusWindowChanged`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#focusWindowChanged) together with the first one.

**Edit:** To make the dialog non-modal, either set `NULL` as it's parent, or set the windowModality-Property to `Qt::NonModal` and show the dialog using `show` and not `open` or `exec`

**Example code in a subclass of QDialog:**

```
connect(QApplication::instance(), SIGNAL(applicationStateChanged(Qt::ApplicationState)), this, SLOT(changeAlwaysOnTop(Qt::ApplicationState)));

...

void MyDialog::changeAlwaysOnTop(Qt::ApplicationState state)
{
    if (state == Qt::ApplicationActive)
        setWindowFlags(windowFlags() | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
    else
        setWindowFlags(windowFlags() & ~Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
    show();
}
```

Comment: This works, but it's still not ideal.  When a window's flags are changed, it is hidden, so I need to call show() afterward.  The result is that when the application state changes, the dialog disappears and reappears, creating a flicker effect.  It makes things look odd and glitchy when the OS focus changes to and from the program.

Comment: Check my new answere below, it seems I found a solution

Comment: I revisited this and the flicker effect isn't as bad as I remembered - maybe my faster computer helps or something's different in OS X 10.11.  Regardless, I think this works as a permanent solution.

Comment: For those who still have issues with the flickering, calling setUpdatesEnabled(false) before setting window flags, and calling setUpdatesEnabled(true) after calling show fixes the flickering issue for me

Answer (score 1):

The default QWidget is enough for your needs.

If you create QWidget with parent to your mainwindow it will be on top of other widgets. You just have to create it last or stack it properly with QWidget::raise().

Comment: That may work for widgets within a window, but I just gave this a try, to no avail.  When I make the QDialog, I set the MainWindow as its parent.  But whether or not I call QWidget::raise(), the MainWindow still comes to the top when it gets focus.  This makes the dialog 'lost' behind the MainWindow, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Then just create QDialog on heap with parent to mainwindow and show it with show(). This will produce behavior that you need.

Comment: That is what I'm doing right now, and it satisfies my second requirement.  But if the dialog uses the Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint window flag, my third requirement isn't met, and if it doesn't use that flag, the first requirement isn't met.

Answer (score 1):

I know I already posted an answere, but I found the best solution:

Use [`QDockWidget`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdockwidget.html). A DockWidget will always stay on top of it's parent, and if you set the `allowedAreas` property to `Qt::NoDockWidgetArea`, the window will behave the way you need it!

Comment: This works, but QDockWidgets have some annoyances (at least on OS X).  They have an odd style for title bars and buttons, they can't be manually resized, and when the program loses focus, they disappear.  I would prefer a solution that behaves this way but with the look and feel of a QDialog.

Answer (score 0):

QMessageBox Inherits QDialog, the following code statify all requirements

```
msgBox = new QMessageBox(QApplication::activeWindow());
msgBox->setModal(false);
msgBox->setWindowFlags(msgBox->windowFlags() | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
msgBox->show()
```

Answer (score -1):

This window will be always on top:
`self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Dialog | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)`

Or you can pass your existing flags:
`self.setWindowFlags( self.windowFlags() | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)`

Answer (score -1):

I can reproduce the original problem only if the QDialog is created with a NULL parent. Otherwise the following lines are sufficient to accomodate requirement 1, 2 and 3.

```
dlg=new MyDialog(applicationMainWidget);
dlg->show();
```